# stop ffmpeg gently (to allow it to finish writing mp4 file) when streaming from udp

Tags: video, ffmpeg, udp, video-streaming

i'm trying to receive a udp stream on a server and write it to an mp4 file. this works fine:

```
  ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:12345 -codec copy out.mp4
```

if i press CTRL+C (or send SIGINT to the process) the ffmpeg quits and i have a working mp4 file.

however, if the data stops coming in on the udp port (e.g. after 10 minutes of streaming) and i try to stop ffmpeg it requires 2 interrupt signals at which point ffmpeg exits abruptly and results in an unplayable mp4 file.

does anyone know how to prevent ffmpeg from hanging when there's no input data or to force it to write out the mp4 header?

i know i can specify a url option

```
 udp://127.0.0.1:12345?timeout=<microseconds>
```

however, i need to be able to ignore occasional (5-10 minute long) pauses during the process of recording and only quit at the end. 
so even if i set timeout=60000000 it will cause my app to wait for 10 minutes when i want to stop the stream (e.g. if there's no data) and i need it to quit immediately when i send a SIGINT to it

Comment: It is 2021, and this behavior is still observable, leading to corupted .mp4. `ffmpeg version 3.4.6 Linux` The sole solution is still to save chunks and merge, meaning extra processing. Or of course, alternatively, while using the same setup, save to `.mkv` instead. This should works straight away.

Answer (score 3):

You can add movflags, even you forced stopped ffmpeg, you will still have playable mp4 file.
`ffmpeg -i input -movflags +frag_keyframe+separate_moof+omit_tfhd_offset+empty_moov output`

More details here (Gyan's answer):
https://video.stackexchange.com/a/18179/33701

It's better to use other format to record live videos. I use MKV, which is not as strict as MP4 and can tolerate some errors.
Also, add flags like `-reconnect_streamed 1`, ffmpeg will try to reconnect if error occurs.

Example:
`ffmpeg -reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 3 -i input -c copy out.mkv`

Docs: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html

Answer (score -1):

found a workaround: if there's no data coming in, forward an image (e.g. green screen) as a video to the required port. e.g.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -y -re -i greenscreen.jpg -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -an -f h264 udp://127.0.0.1:12345
```

that way the ffmpeg writing the mp4 file will stop gracefully but you might get 1-2 seconds of the green screen video at the end.

problem is, i'm not sure how to detect the 'no data' automatically

Answer (score -1):

Sending SIGINT to ffmpeg process is gently kills it with saving header properly.
At least for versions after 2.5.7

Comment: if there's no data coming in, SIGINT (even for versions after 2.5.7) creates a corrupted mp4, hence why i suggested a workaround